# Radio list with SelectedIndexChanged not firing inside radgrid

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, postback, telerik-grid, onselect

I  have a user control that contains a radio list that on SelectIndexChanged it updates a drop down.
I put together a basic page and add the user control to the page it works fine but when I move the control to inside a radgrid it doesn't work, it will post back but never call the SelectIndexChanged event.

I've pulled up 2 previous questions on this [Q. 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463398/assign-an-event-to-a-custom-control-inside-a-repeater-control/463582#463582) and [Q. 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485390/why-isnt-the-selectedindexchanged-event-firing-from-a-dropdownlist-in-a-gridvie) which say that OnSelectedIndexChanged needed to be set in the aspx page. My issue is that the control doesn't exist in the aspx page and is created later so that solution does not work for me.

*Working code*

**working.aspx**

```
<TT:ToolTipControl ID="ToolTipEdit" runat="server" />
```

**working.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolTipEdit.getEditToolTip("POL_TERM_CD", "DataPolTermDropDownlistEdit");
}
```

*User Control*

**userControl.ascx.cs**

```
public void getEditToolTip(string fieldName, string ddlName)
{
     DataPolTermRadioListBox ccPolTermRadioListBox = new DataPolTermRadioListBox(); //custom radio list
     ccPolTermRadioListBox.ID = "PolTermRadioListBox";
     ccPolTermRadioListBox.AutoPostBack = true;
     ccPolTermRadioListBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(updateParent);
     ToolTip.Controls.Add(ccPolTermRadioListBox);
}
```

*Broken Code*

**brokenPage.aspx**

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgState" Skin="WebBlue" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="rgState_NeedDataSource"
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPreRender="rgState_PreRender">
     <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="wrtnStPolId" AllowAutomaticUpdates="false" AllowAutomaticDeletes="true"
         AllowAutomaticInserts="false" CommandItemDisplay="Top" AllowMultiColumnSorting="True"
         EditMode="InPlace" GroupLoadMode="Server" Caption="State(s) and Exposure(s)">
         <Columns>
             <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="false" HeaderText="Pol Type Nstd" SortExpression="nonStdPolTypeCd"
                 UniqueName="nonStdPolTypeCd">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblNonStdPolTypeCd" runat="server" align="center" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "nonStdPolTypeCd")%>' />

                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                     <cc1:DataNonStdTypeCdDropDownList ID="ddlNonStdTypeCd" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Predictable">
                     </cc1:DataNonStdTypeCdDropDownList>
                     <TT:ToolTipControl ID="ttcNonStdPolTypeCdEdit" runat="server" />
                 </EditItemTemplate>
             </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
         </Columns>
     </MasterTableView>
 </telerik:RadGrid>
```

**brokenPage.aspx.cs**

```
protected void rgState_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            RadGrid rgExpMod = (RadGrid)sender;

            foreach (GridDataItem row in rgExpMod.Items)
            {

                    GridDataItem gdiItem = (GridDataItem)row;

                    if (row.FindControl("ttcNonStdPolTypeCdEdit") != null)
                    {

                        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlNonStdTypeCd");
                        ddl.ID += row.RowIndex;
                        ddl.SelectedIndex = 2;

                        NCCI.PDC.Web.Controls.ucToolTip ttcNonStdPolTypeCdEdit = (NCCI.PDC.Web.Controls.ucToolTip)row.FindControl("ttcNonStdPolTypeCdEdit");
                        ttcNonStdPolTypeCdEdit.getEditToolTip("non_std_pol_type_cd", ddl.ID);

                    }
            }

        }
```